# Why application packet rate setting in Castilian doesn't occur exactly?

Tags: omnet++

I used Castalia simulator for compare my routing protocol with 2 other protocol.
I setted the application packet rate = 30 p/s for a special node in all 3 protocol, and run the codes, but none of these protocols produced packet with rate exactly 30 p/s! I want to understand its reason.

Comment: You should provide a bit more details in your question. Which application are you using? Do you have a minimal example that demonstrates your problem?

Comment: I used a application that i wrote it, but it is similar to throughput_test application. for example i set application packet rate = 30 p/s, but one of my routing protocol logs shows about 26 p/s and another shows 28 p/s.

Comment: my guess is that you're comparing a packet send rate with a reception rate. If you mean the [ThroughputTest](https://github.com/boulis/Castalia/blob/42d8531e36b79d102fa81922bd8d340fa2d61f9e/Castalia/src/node/application/throughputTest/ThroughputTest.cc) application, then as you can see in [this line](https://github.com/boulis/Castalia/blob/42d8531e36b79d102fa81922bd8d340fa2d61f9e/Castalia/src/node/application/throughputTest/ThroughputTest.cc#L33), the value packet_rate is used to set how often packets are sent, not the rate you see in the receiver.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is likely related to one or both of the following:

1. you're setting the transmission rate, and you're expecting that you see that many packets on both ends of your route
2. you're measuring the packet rate incorrectly (e.g., there's some bug, or you're ignoring packets you should be counting)

It's difficult to say what the precise problem is without access to code, but these are the two avenues that you should investigate whenever you encounter this type of problem. In the case of 1., you'll want to look at the exact properties of the message generation code; in the case of 2., I'd recommend counting things individually as much as possible, so that you can see which of your protocols causes the discrepancy, and work from there.